# Помогите поправить php код

Tags: php

Html код формы:

```
<form action="orders/handler.php" method="POST">
    <label for="contactName">Name <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>

    <label for="email">E-Mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>

    <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone_number">

    <label for="emailTo">Service <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="service">Window Washing 
    <input type="checkbox">Gutter Cleaning
    <input type="checkbox">Power Washing

    <label for="message">Message <span>*</span></label>
    <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Php код:

```js
    <?php
$name='';
$phone_number='';
$email='';
$service='';
$message='';

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
}
if(isset($_POST['phone_number'])){
    $phone_number=htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone_number']);
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
}
if(isset($_POST['service'])){
    $service=htmlspecialchars($_POST['service']);
}
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message=htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
}
$mail_message='Имя: '.$name.'
Номер телефона: '.$phone_number.'
E-mail: '.$email.'
Услуга: '.$service.'
Сообщение: '.$message.'
';

file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/orders/list/Order_'.date("j_m_Y H-i-s").'.html', $mail_message);


$item_gift   = '';

/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
$address = "";

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */
$sub = 'Order on the site';// тема
$email = '<sender/>';// от кого
mail($address, $sub, $mail_message, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
?>
```

Как видно поля уже настроены, но не могу доделать чекбоксы, переменная service не записывает их в себя.

Comment: Во первых - у чекбоксов должно быть value и name. Во вторых - в переменную $service придет массив, а не строка

Comment: Знаю, но из языков программирования самостоятельно переделать могу только на JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычно поля input содержат value
например так

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="2">2
```

```
if(isset($_POST['services'])){
    $service=htmlspecialchars(join (', ', $_POST['services']));
}
```

Comment: таким образом записывается 1 значение, а чекбоксов 3

Comment: может быть в таком случае стоит использовать radio баттоны?
type='radio'
или таки нужно несколько значений выбирать?

Comment: в таком случае нельзя будет указать несколько услуг сразу. сделал бы сам, но с php туго. Как я понял, нужно получить значения в массив и записать его в переменную service

Comment: поправил ответ как Вы хотите